# How can I expose Redux store as global variable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, google-chrome-devtools

Basically there is an redux/react app which I inspected in chrome dev tools and I found it has a flag in redux store similar to

```
"premiumFeature": false;
```

So I want to change it just to see what happens, how do I do that ? How can I change it manually ? How can I expose it as global var?

Comment: I would write a chrome extension to automate this store change. This is the reason i want it as global var.

Comment: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/776

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Redux DevTool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd?hl=en) chrome extension, it gonna help you control **dispatching actions**, **getting previous states** and a lot more.

Also, check their docs from [here](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-devtools).